# How to add condition to gurobi

Tags: python, gurobi

I have variables whose values change every hour during the day (24 values):

```
plants = ['Plant1', 'Plant2']
users = ['user1', 'user2']
time_steps = range(0,24)

p_gen = model.addVars(plants, time_steps, name="pow_gen")

tot_consume = model.addVars(users, time_steps, name="total_demand")

p_grid = model.addVars(time_steps, lb = -GRB.INFINITY, name="exch_pow")
```

I want to implement something like this:

```
If ((quicksum(p_gen[t] for pp in plants) - quicksum(tot_d[u,t] for u in users) )>= p_grid[t] for t in time_steps)

model.addConstrs(A)
model.addConstrs(B)

else:

model.addConstrs(C)
```

My problem is that Gurobi does not understand the variables which depend on the time. I want to implement if the condition, so it depends on the condition the program, will you different addConstr.

How to implement this condition in Gurobi?

Answer (score 0):

Linear Programming doesn't work like this.

You have constraints and your model **must** fulfill them, otherwise your model is infeasible.

You can't put constraints based on constraints conditions, if anything you can put constraints based on boolean conditions (like a setting, a value...) or you can put [boolean constraints.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12102/express-boolean-logic-operations-in-zero-one-integer-linear-programming-ilp)

You can, however, have **two** models at the same time, with the same vars and constraints *before* the `if / else` branches.

You can resolve the first model, get the value you need with the `x` attribute (just call `variable.x` to get its value), and with that value you can select which constraints add to second model, and then resolve it.